# Generate multiple columns in EF Model from a List

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to create a model class that replicates a set of data that I need to parse from a csv. In this data, it includes 48 (sometimes 50) half-hour (HH) blocks with nullable `decimal` values. I need to structure my table as follows:

> Identifier|Date|HH1|HH2|HH3|HH4|HH5| etc. up till 50

Now I could do this by easily creating 52 properties. However, I was hoping there was a cleaner way to replicate my requirements by using a `List<string>` that holds these half-hour property names. Keeping in mind that the actual type of these properties needs to be nullable `decimal`.

My question is how would I translate this List into separate columns through EF and furthermore how do I make sure this List is instantiated with the correct property/column names i.e. ("HH1", "HH2" ..)

Comment: This seems like more of a database design issue. Those columns should potentially be rows in a separate table.

Comment: @MattRowland I would prefer to do this a different way but it's a client requirement to have it structured like this.

Comment: Just have a `time` column, group by date and order by time and the sequence will give you the additional identifier.

Comment: Requirements should be a negotiation with the client and the developer.

Comment: Entity Framework is meant to be used by mapping a column to a property. You might want to use ADO to accomplish this.

Comment: @MattRowland Okay, so this requirement is feasible within ADO?

Comment: I don't think this should be done at all so I wouldn't label it *feasible*. However, it can be accomplished using ADO as just about everything is possible.

Comment: @MattRowland Then would you say it was better to just create all the properties separately?

Comment: Yes, but only because you cannot alter the database structure.

Comment: @MattRowland Okay, thanks for the advice.